# textbook on the human brain for computer scientists/machine learning professionals?

Tags: reference-request, neural-networks

The human brain as studied by neuroscientists, or neurobiologists, generally focus on what I would call

- implementation details (how specifically does information transport between synaptic channels, i.e. what are the chemical processes)
- vague generalities (e.g. about "memory" as a psychological concept and in very vague terms what types of memory there are without studying them mathematically)

There is nothing intrinsically wrong with this.

But I am interested in the brain as a computational system. Of course we don't yet understand the brain very well, but **is there a book on the brain that a computer scientist or machine learning professional could read to get a computational/systematic understanding of what we know about the brain?** e.g. what is the computational role of various neurotransmitters (without going into chemistry), etc.

Comment: You should know by now that questions like this don't work well here...

Comment: The answer is simply: no, unless things like https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fninf.2014.00037/full are sufficient for you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "textbook" on this. However, there is a book! It is [How to Create a Mind](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1491518839) by [Raymond Kurzweil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_Kurzweil), the director of engineering at Google. Excellent book that explains the brain from a computer-science perspective. It goes into a lot of detail.

Check out the intro sound bytes on [Audible](https://www.audible.com/pd/Science-Technology/How-to-Create-a-Mind-Audiobook/B009S7OKJS).

For a closer to the metal (i.e. actual implementations of models of the brain), check out Cognitive Architectures, such as ACT-R, Soar, CLARION, ICARUS, EPIC, LIDA, etc. Here is a [survey](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.08602.pdf).